# Optimizing a SQL expression generating Pareto's Points - How to efficiently group by each combination?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, optimization, query-optimization

You don't really need to know here that it is generating Pareto's points; but we never know, maybe someone will say "just use the hidden awesome built-in pareto function!".

### The problem

I have a query returning:

```
resource | activity_percentage
1 | P(1)
2 | P(2)
3 | P(3)
...
N - 1 | P(N - 1)
N | P(N)
```

Where:

- N is the total number of resources
- P is a function giving the activity percentage of a given resource; just to make it easier to read.
- P(1) >= P(2) >= .. >= P(N - 1) >= P(N); the resource 1 has the highest activity percentage, the resource N has the lowest, ...

I need to group the resources one by one ({1}, {1; 2}, {1; 2; 3}, ...; {1; 2; ...; N}), accumulating the activity_percentage of the resources present in the group. The final result will be:

```
resource_percentage | activity_percentage
R(1) | A(1)
R(2) | A(2)
...
R(N - 1) | A(N - 1)
```

Where

- R(X) is the percentage of resources present in the the group number X. So R(X) = X/N. For example: Group 1 includes the resource 1; Group 2 includes 1 and 2; Group N includes the resources 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., N - 2, N - 1 and N. R(N) = 1
- A(X) is the accumulation of the percentages of each resource in the group. A(X) = P(1) + ... + P(X). For example: A(1) = P(1) since group 1 only includes 1; A(4) = P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4) since group 4 includes 1, 2, 3 and 4.

### My Solution

### 1. Query to get a resource rank and its activity percentage

```
-- Query assigning a number to each resource according to its rank of activity percentage.
SELECT
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY activity_percentage DESC)  AS resource,
  activity_percentage                                   AS activity_percentage
FROM
  Resource_Table
```

We obtain here:

```
resource | activity_percentage
1 | P(1)
2 | P(2)
3 | P(3)
...
N - 1 | P(N - 1)
N | P(N)
```

### 2. Create a serie of number from 1 to N

Is there a SQL feature doing that? For now, I use the same query as above, which is bad and slow...

```
-- Creates a serie from 1 to the number of resources
SELECT
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY activity_percentage DESC) AS i
FROM
  Resource_Table
```

We obtain:

```
i
1
2
3
...
N
```

### 3. Add the percentage of resources contained per group

To be able to say, for example, group 1 contains only 1 which represent (100 * 1/N) percent of resources; group N contains every resources; 100 * N / N = 100%

```
SELECT
  i, -- i is the number of the group but it actually gives the number of resources it contains too
  cast(i AS float) / resources.nb_resources AS resource_percentage
FROM
( -- Creates a number serie from 1 to the number of resources
  SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY activity_percentage DESC)   AS i
  FROM
    Resource
) groups
JOIN
( -- Query only getting the number of resources...
  SELECT
    count(DISTINCT resource_id) AS nb_resources
  FROM
    Resource_Table
) customers ON 1 = 1
```

I hate this one since I am doing another query to get the number of resources, which is finally max(i) or the number of lines returned by the query (count(*))...

### 4. Group the resources together

So now, we just have to join these queries with the condition: resource <= i

```
SELECT
  groups.i                      AS group_number,
  groups.resource_percentage,
  activity_percentage.resource,
  activity_percentage.activity_percentage  
FROM
(
  SELECT
    i, -- i is the number of the group but it actually gives the number of resources it contains too
    cast(i AS float) / resources.nb_resources   AS resource_percentage
  FROM
  ( -- Creates a number serie from 1 to the number of resources
    SELECT
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY activity_percentage DESC) AS i
    FROM
      Resource
  ) groups
  JOIN
  ( -- Query only getting the number of resources...
    SELECT
      count(DISTINCT resource_id)   AS nb_resources
    FROM
      Resource_Table
  ) customers ON 1 = 1
) groups
JOIN
( -- Query assigning a number to every resource according to its activity percentage.
  SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY activity_percentage DESC)  AS resource,
    activity_percentage                                 AS activity_percentage
  FROM
    Resource_Table
) activity_percentage ON activity_percentage.resource <= groups.i
```

We obtain:

```
group_number | resource_percentage | resource | activity_percentage
1 | R(1) | 1 | P(1)

2 | R(2) | 1 | P(1)
2 | R(2) | 2 | P(2)

3 | R(3) | 1 | P(1)
3 | R(3) | 2 | P(2)
3 | R(3) | 3 | P(3)

...

N | R(N) | 1 | P(1)
N | R(N) | 2 | P(2)
N | R(N) | ... | ...
N | R(N) | N | P(N)
```

### 5. Simply aggregate per group_number

Changing the above query:

```
SELECT
  groups.resource_percentage,
  sum(activity_percentage.activity_percentage) AS activity_percentage
FROM
  ...
GROUP BY
  groups.resource_percentage
```

Grouping by the group_number or group_percentage does not matter since each group_number has a corresponding group_percentage.

That's it! We obtain:

```
resource_percentage | activity_percentage
R(1) | A(1) = P(1)
R(2) | A(2) = P(1) + P(2)
...
R(N) | A(N) = P(1) + P(2) + ... + P(N)
```

Graphically:
[image]

### Conclusion

I obtain a very long query, mostly due to the creation of groups (my N is 25 550) but I would be very pleased to know a better solution, mostly for steps 2 & 3.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515525/optimizing-a-sql-expression-generating-paretos-points-how-to-efficiently-group/4515685#4515685), I modified my query like that:

```
SELECT
    groups.resource_percentage,
    sum(customer_calls_percentage.activity_percentage)  AS activity_percentage
FROM
( -- This new subquery is more efficient compared to the last one (3s instead of 11)
  -- We get the group number and the percentage of ressources it contains in a single query
  SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(Activity.activity_id) DESC)                                   AS i,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(Activity.activity_id) DESC) / cast(count(*) OVER() AS float)  AS resource_percentage
  FROM
    Activity
  JOIN
    Resource ON Resource.activity_id = Activity.activity_id
  GROUP BY
    resource_id
) groups
JOIN
( -- This one is faster too.
  SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(Activity.activity_id) DESC) AS resource,
    cast(count(Activity.activity_id) AS float) / sum(count(Activity.activity_id)) OVER () AS activity_percentage
  FROM
    Activity
  JOIN
    Resource ON Resource.resource_id = Activity.activity_id
  GROUP BY
    resource_id
) resource_activity_percentage ON resource_activity_percentage.resource <= groups.i
GROUP BY
  groups.resource_percentage
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure if my code is correct, since i'm not on a pc with a database engine; but I think that you can do all of your queries in a few steps.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY activity_percentage DESC)  AS resource,
       activity_percentage AS activity_percentage,
       COUNT(*) OVER() AS N
INTO #Resources
FROM Resource_Table

SELECT CAST(resource AS FLOAT)/N AS resource_percentage, 
       (SELECT SUM(activity_percentage) FROM #Resources WHERE resource<=RT.resource) Activiy_percentage
FROM #Resources AS RT
```

Hope it helps.
**UPDATED**
Well, since your new query works better for you, I guess you could try this change to see if it works faster:

```
;WITH Resource_Table AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(Activity.activity_id) DESC) AS i,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(Activity.activity_id) DESC) / CAST(COUNT(*) OVER() AS FLOAT) AS resource_percentage,
        CAST(COUNT(Activity.activity_id) AS FLOAT) / (SUM(COUNT(Activity.activity_id)) OVER ()) AS activity_percentage
FROM Activity
JOIN [Resource] ON [Resource].activity_id = Activity.activity_id
GROUP BY resource_id
)
SELECT  A.resource_percentage,
        SUM(B.activity_percentage) AS activity_percentage
FROM Resource_Table AS A
JOIN Resource_Table AS B
ON B.i <= A.i
GROUP BY A.resource_percentage
```

Comment: yes, it does (help). You subquery is time saving. I am discovering the "OVER". I am trying to create a new version with that. +1

Comment: glad it helped you. Let me know if it gives you the output you wanted, or if it needs further work.

Comment: The query is finished after 15min which is longer than what I had. But my new subqueries using OVER are faster... See Edit1

Comment: Ok, thats no good, I updated my answer so you can try another aproach.